# Convert GPS coordinates (lat, long) to local coordinates system

Tags: c#, gps, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I want to place a series of points on a plane. I have its gps coordinates, in the plane I have several reference point(with latitude and longitude associated). How can I place those points from those reference points?

Answer (score 0):

To project a LatLong coordinate to a plane you should use a map projection.
There are many different map projections (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections), each of them has it's own special feature.

For example Google and other tile maps  use Mercator-Projection (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection).